# UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8 but exists in object library Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uisearchcontroller

I drag the search bar and search display controller on to storyboard. And in the view controller, I am implementing the UISearchDisplay delegate. But it tells me it's deprecated in iOS 8. So, How do I add a search controller to storyboard and implement the delegate and datasource? Does it make sense?

Right now I am using the replacement: UISearchController. When the search display controller in object library will be replaced with UISearchController.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create UISearchController, which was introduced with iOS 8, via storyboard right now. Maybe in future versions of XCode.

So you have to create the UISearchController with Code. Checkout this [example project from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: If I try to do this **in code** there is also `searchDisplayController` property (what is currently deprecated). So I still cannot see possibilities to do `UISearchController` by code...